# Discarding nulls after full outer join in PIG

Tags: hadoop, join, apache-pig

Need help with discarding nulls in the result of full outer join in pig Latin. Below are two data sets :

A:

```
(BOS,2)
(BUR,81)
(LAS,8)
```

B:

```
(BUR,56)
(EWR,2)
(LAS,88)
```

After full outer join : 
C :

```
(BOS,2,,)
(BUR,81,BUR,56)
(,,EWR,2)
(LAS,8,LAS,88)
```

I need to get the output in below format :

```
(BOS,2)
(BUR,137)
(EWR,2)
(LAS,96)
```

Tried different combinations of group by , flatten , bagtotuple ... but was not able to figure out the solution . Many thanks for help.

```
airline = load '/demo/data/airline/airline.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (Origin: chararray, Dest: chararray); 
traffic_in = GROUP airline by Origin; 
traffic_in_count= FOREACH traffic_in generate group as Origin , COUNT(airline) as count ; 
traffic_out = GROUP airline by Dest; 
traffic_out_count = FOREACH traffic_out generate group as Dest ,COUNT (airline) as count; 
traffic_top = JOIN traffic_in_count by Origin FULL OUTER , traffic_out_count by Dest ;
```

Comment: please share you pig script. seem you can use cogroup and so SUM - did you try it ?

Comment: airline = load '/demo/data/airline/airline.csv' using PigStorage(',') 
            as (Origin: chararray, Dest: chararray);
    

    
traffic_in = GROUP airline by Origin;
traffic_in_count= FOREACH traffic_in generate group as Origin , COUNT(airline) as count  ;

    traffic_out = GROUP airline by Dest;
traffic_out_count = FOREACH traffic_out generate group as Dest ,COUNT (airline) as count;

     traffic_top = JOIN traffic_in_count by Origin FULL OUTER , traffic_out_count by Dest ;     ---please excuse me , not able to format the  code --

Comment: Above is my actual code , replaced the aliases in the question .

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Instead of using OUTER JOIN use [UNION](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#union) and then [SUM](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#sum) the 2nd column values.

```
A = LOAD 'test1.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (A1:chararray, A2:int); 
B = LOAD 'test2.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (B1:chararray, B2:int); 
C = UNION A,B;
D = GROUP C BY $0;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE group,SUM(C.$1);
DUMP E;
```

**Output**

[image: Total]

Comment: same output after the above filter option ... result not obtained.

Comment: @Fasahat I've updated the answer.Instead of join you can UNION and get the total.